# How to filter ObservableCollection resursively

Tags: c#, wpf, filtering

I have an observable collection that contains a list of monitors. 
With each monitor able to contain an observable collection of monitors (create a tree structure).

I need to be able to filter recursively.

What I currently have is

```
public void Filter()
{
    ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Monitors);
    collectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterOutZero);

    //foreach (Monitor monitor in Monitors)
    //   monitor.Children.Filter();
}
```

The FilterOutZero function return true/false depending on the state of the monitor.

I can get it working for the first level of the observable collection, but I am struggling to filter the inner collections.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you do with result of the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Make your Filter function into an extention method an observable collection?

```
public void Filter<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a property Filter in Monitor class.
This property is initialized when filter for Monitors is added.
Apply this filter to monitors inside Monitor

```
 public class Monitor
    {
        private Predicate<object> _filter;
        public Predicate<object> Filter
        {
            get { return _filter; }
            set 
            {
                _filter = value;
                ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(test);
                collectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(_filter);
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Monitor> monitor{ get; set; }

            }

public void Filter()
        {
            ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Monitors);
            collectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterOutZero);
            foreach (var l in Monitors)
            {
                l.Filter = collectionView.Filter;

            }
        }
```